# Android Studio SDK Manager tools not showing un-checked items

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

In `SDK Manager >> SDK Tools` I want to check another item say `Android SDK Platform-Tools` but this item and all other un-checked items are not showing there. Is there anything wrong with my IDE settings?

*My Android studio version is 2021.2.1*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some try and errors I just found that SDK Tools retrieve its list from the Internet.

In the other hand dl.google.com is returning 403 in my locale (because of sanctions).
So I set a proxy on my system Linux and tell Android-Studio to use that proxy and it solved the problem.

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately it seems not being a development question and may not be helpful for most guys. But I hope this helps some ones like me.